# Repeat a question from Math Overflow ?

Tags: discussion

If one have asked a question on MO, is it correct to ask it again on CSTheory ?

In my case, my question is more than one week old, and even if it had some interesting answer, there was not any real correct answer.

On one hand, I think in general it is not good that the discussion is divised in two places.
On other hand I guess it may reach a more interested public here, and hopefully it may help me obtain a better answer.

Comment: See http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25/material-to-supplement-the-faq/36#36 – in brief, it's correct to ask it again here, but please add a link to your MO question.

Answer (score 5):

I think that one week is a good time to consider crossposting.  If you do so, please add links *in both directions* so that people who read your question at either place will have a chance to know everything posted at the other place.  You can add a comment to the older post if you do not want to bump the question on the top page.

Since the [FAQ entry about crossposting](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/231#231) links here, I would like to express my opinion about something other than what is asked in this question, namely about crossposting in a short period of time (such as one day).  I feel that it is unfair that some people crosspost a question in more than one place, usually MathOverflow and cstheory.stackexchange.com.  Of course everyone wants to get his/her question answered as quickly as possible, and exposing the question in many places increases the chance.  But they should refrain from doing that, like the rest of us.

Some new users seem to crosspost questions because they do not know where the best place to ask is.  I do not think that it is the right reason for crossposting, either.  For them, I would recommend the following:

1. Read each of the candidate websites a little so that you can make an educated guess about where the best place for your question is.
2. Post your question at only one website.
3. If you do not get a satisfactory answer in one week or so, crosspost the question on another website if you want to.  Do not forget to link in both directions!

Comment: It is selfish, or at least self-centered.  However, Tsuyoshi, I think you are letting this bother you too much.  You are assuming malice, when it is more correct to assume cluelessness.  I think people have no idea that some of the same people look both places, or that they might get overlapping answers both places.  Yes, they should know that, but, hey, if I knew everything I should know, I'd know a hell of a lot.

Comment: @Aaron: Fair enough.  As a general principle, I agree that we should assume that others are in good faith.  I guess that I should cool down.

Comment: I rewrote the answer to focus on a possible solution, not on a rant.

Comment: I've posted a q at meta.SO asking if we can extend the close reasons to include exact duplicates on non SE 2.0 sites.